# How to stop hiredis command?

Tags: asynchronous, hiredis

I am using [hiredis library](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) in my project. I'm using async API. I schedule a read command and wait for data. That works fine. However problem occurs when I try to close the connection - I call redisAsyncDisconnect, however the callback routine isn't called until I receive data.

Is it possible to cancel the read operation? How? Or is there a way how to force close the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is clear now - redisAsyncFree does what I need - stops all commands and calls redisAsyncDisconnect.